# Unity2D: play instantiated prefab's animation when prefab is being dragged

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation

I have a prefab that is instantiated when the user buys the item from my In-game store, how ever many is instantiated, the all of prefab has a start position of a certain position. The prefab can be dragged around the scene using [this](https://github.com/TouchScript/TouchScript/wiki) TouchScript package I found online! My issue: I want to play the prefab's animation every time the user is dragging the prefab around the screen, I attempted this by creating a RaycastHit2D function that would allow me to detect if the user has clicked on the prefab's collider, script below:

```
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        Vector2 worldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (worldPoint, Vector2.zero);
        if (hit.collider != null) {
            if (this.gameObject.name == "Item5 (1)(Clone)" +item5Increase.i) {
                monkeyAnim.SetBool ("draging", true);
                Debug.Log (hit.collider.name);
            }
        } else {
            monkeyAnim.SetBool ("draging", false);
        }
    }
```

However if I were to buy more than one prefab, all instantiated prefabs will play it's animation when I start to drag only one of the instantiated prefabs, hope I'm making sense. Can some one help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced a similar issue with platforms in my 2D game. The solution I would suggest is to create a `GameObject` that acts as the current item you wish to animate, and a `LayerMask` that acts as a filter for which objects your raycast can hit. You can use this `LayerMask` in conjunction with the [`Physics2D.Raycast` API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html), which has an overload method that takes a `LayerMask` as a parameter.

Start by creating a new layer, which can be done by going to the top right of an object in your scene and accessing the "Layer" box. Once you've created a new layer (I called mine "item"), make sure your prefab's layer is assigned correctly.

Then, create an empty object in your scene, and attach this script to it. On that object you will see a dropdown menu that asks which layers your raycast should hit. Assign it the "item" layer; this ensures that your raycast can only hit objects in that layer, so clicking on anything else in your game will produce no effect.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ItemAnimation : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject itemToAnimate;
    private Animator itemAnim;

    [SerializeField]
    private LayerMask itemMask;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            CheckItemAnimations();
        }

        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && itemToAnimate != null) //reset the GameObject once the user is no longer holding down the mouse
        {
            itemAnim.SetBool("draging", false);
            itemToAnimate = null;
        }
    }

    private void CheckItemAnimations()
    {
        Vector2 worldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(worldPoint, Vector2.zero, 1, itemMask);

        if (hit) //if the raycast hit an object in the "item" layer
        {
            itemToAnimate = hit.collider.gameObject;

            itemAnim = itemToAnimate.GetComponent<Animator>();
            itemAnim.SetBool("draging", true);

            Debug.Log(itemToAnimate.name);
        }

        else //the raycast didn't make contact with an item
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I tried out what you suggested but i still am having a few issues, such as I get null references if were to click anywhere within my game, meaning the else statement isn't working...the response time for when I'm dragging my item around is slow, such as it require me to click on the item twice and drag it around in order for my animation to play and get the debug.log telling me the item's name. Thank you again for the help, I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: I updated my answer with some new code to fix the null exception. Regarding the animations being slow, it might be an issue with the touch script you're using, or perhaps you have not removed animation delays in the animation window. All animations in Unity are created with "exit time" and "transition duration", both of which must be removed if you want to animate instantly. I made sure to remove those, then tested this in a project, and everything seems to work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it work!!! Thank you, however, I don't think the animation is the problem because I don't have "has exit time" on or have a long "transition duration" within my animation. I could be the touch script I'm using but I'm not an advance coder, lol! Do you have any idea what I can do? Again, I really appreciate the help! Thank you so much!

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know the specifics of your project, but your best bet might be to try to code your own drag and drop functionality. There are many online tutorials available for this, and you would probably have an easier time linking it with your other code than trying to figure out a script someone else wrote that might have a lot more functionality than you need. 

I generally try to avoid using Unity packages and third party code because I find that it sometimes costs me more time than it saves.